# Как найти позицию подстроки в строке?

Tags: c++, строки

Ищу наличие подстроки в строке, но не знаю, как сделать это правильно. Например, мне нужна позиция `substring` в `string`.

***Что у меня есть:***

```
string string = "somedomain";
string substring = "domain";
```

***Попытка использовать `strstr()`:***

```
strstr(string, substring);
```

Это не работает из-за неверных типов. Как мне использовать строки `string` в этой функции?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow in Russian. As the name implies, Russian is the working language of this site. Please either translate your question into Russian or [ask the same question on StackOverflow in English](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Your question may be closed soon, but it will most likely be reopened if you choose to translate it.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `.c_str()`:

```
strstr(str.c_str(), substring.c_str());
```

Только зачем вам это? Это же применение функций C в языке C++ - для чего? Если вы хотите найти в строке подстроку, то используйте [`.find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).

Comment: раз ответили, вам и приводить вопрос в порядок — перевести его на русский язык (автор, судя по всему, забил на это).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Да без проблем :)